# Precambrian shield and Don Valley Brickworks

Tags: geology, precambrian, canada

living in Toronto, and interested in Geology, I am looking for some information on where the Precambrian shield rocks found in the Don Valley / Evergreen Brickworks originated. More specifically, can someone shed some light on how they got there, and what they are called?

Comment: See http://www.lostrivers.ca/points/BrickworksNorthwall.htm